# Утопить слайды с уменьшением

Tags: html, css, css3

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот HTML

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#" class="thumb_1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#" class="thumb_1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#" class="thumb_1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#" class="thumb_1"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#" class="thumb_1"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот CSS

```
.thumb_1 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 352px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #367FD3;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Не получается утопить слайды как на макете. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: `transform: scale(0.8);` для не активных или же `transform: scale(1.2);` для активного Значение `scale` подбирайте сами

Comment: Пробовал такое, но в итоге отступы между слайдами разные. А нужно чтобы получились одинаковые

Comment: @Denis У вам на первом слайде тоже отступы разные